# Problem using MPI in a python program when testing it with a gitlab-ci.yml pipeline

Tags: python, gitlab

I have a python code hosted in gitlab. Recently, I have added the use of to handle parallel runs with MPI. I have a testsuite that is launched by the gitlab CI system. However, it fails as soon as it tries to install the mpi4py package.

I am using the python 3.7 image. The .gitlab-ci.yml file is:

```
image: python:3.7

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - python setup.py build
    - python setup.py install
    - pytest --junitxml=report.xml -v tests/short.py
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - report.xml
    reports:
      junit: report.xml
```

The failure happens when, upon installing the mpi4py package as requested in the requirements.txt file, the build process fails with
the message:

```
 gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      _configtest.c:2:10: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
          2 | #include <mpi.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      error: Cannot compile MPI programs. Check your configuration!!!
      [end of output]
```

I suppose that the mpi C library is missing? How should I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to have a look at how to install `libmpich-dev` in general (https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#linux).

gcc should be present in your container already.

in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` add these two lines:

**EDIT**
If you have trouble finding the package run the following in you container

`apt update`

`apt-get install -y libmpich-dev`

you script should look like:

```
image: python:3.7

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - apt update
    - apt-get install -y libmpich-dev
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - python setup.py build
    - python setup.py install
    - pytest --junitxml=report.xml -v tests/short.py
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - report.xml
    reports:
      junit: report.xml
```

Comment: Thanks WArnold. It is probably the problem, but I am still confused. I cannot install  libmpich-dev simply doing "apt-get install -y libmpich-dev" because the package is not found ("Unable to locate package libmpich-dev". That is the name of the package in debian, but how do I know what distro is actually the image that I am using? How can one know what is the right name of the package that needs to be installed?

Comment: Can you run docker in interactive mode? I'm asking because I was able to `apt-get install -y libmpich-dev` from docker image `python:3.7`
`docker run <image-id> sh` and `apt-get install -y libmpich-dev`

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it! It was the "apt update" that I was not using before the "apt-get install".